# Functor maps a morphism to empty morphism

Tags: category-theory

Let $F$ be a functor from categories $C$ to $D$. Is it allowed for the functor to map a morphism to empty map? So $f:A\rightarrow B$ in $C$ is mapped to nothing in $\operatorname{Hom}_D(F(A),F(B))$.

Comment: No, this is not allowed. In particular, the assignment $f \mapsto F(f) : \operatorname{Hom}_C(A,B) \to \operatorname{Hom}_D(F(A),F(B))$ must be a function!

Comment: I see. $\operatorname{Hom}(-,-)$ is a set. Thanks!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk that is an answer, post it!

Comment: The comment by @diracdeltafunk correctly answers your question about  "mapped to nothing". On the other hand, in some categories(e.g. the category  of sets) there are  morphisms that, considered as functions, are the empty map. These morphisms can perfectly well be among the values of a functor. So if that's what you meant by "map a morphism to the empty map" then the answer to your question would be yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested in comments above, I'll expand my comment into an answer.

The definition of "functor" is as follows:

**Definition** Let $C$ and $D$ be categories. A *functor* from $C$ to $D$ consists of the following assignments:

1. For each object $X$ of $C$, an object $F(X)$ of $D$
2. For each pair $(X,Y)$ of objects in $C$, a function $F_{X,Y} : \operatorname{Hom}_C(X,Y) \to \operatorname{Hom}_D(F(X),F(Y))$

Satisfying the following conditions:

1. $F(\operatorname{id}_X) = \operatorname{id}_{F(X)}$ for all objects $X$ of $C$
2. $F_{Y,Z}(g) \circ F_{X,Y}(h) = F_{X,Z}(g \circ h)$ for all composable pairs of morphisms $(g : Y \to Z, h : X \to Y)$ in $C$

Normally the subscripts on the functions $F_{X,Y}$ are omitted, making the second condition much easier to read: $F(g) \circ F(h) = F(g \circ h)$.

In any case, by the very definition of functor, every morphism $f : X \to Y$ in $C$ must be sent to a morphism $F(f) : F(X) \to F(Y)$. In other words, it is illegal to have "$f : A \to B$ ... mapped to nothing".

However, as @Andreas Blass wisely points out in the comments, this is very different from asking if a functor may "map a morphism to empty map" – if there is a morphism $e$ in $D$ called "empty map", there is definitely a category $C$ and a functor $F : C \to D$ such that $F(f) = e$ for some morphism $f$ in $C$. It is probably a good idea to gauge your current level of ability by trying to construct such a functor!